# Sedgewick analysis of algorithm, difference between theory of algorithm and scientific approach

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I'm trying to improve my skills in analysis of algorithms. I think Sedgewick's "introduction to the analysis of algorithm" is a good, I'm reading carefully the first chapter, at least I'm trying. And the following is mentioned:

> The first, popularized by Aho, Hopcroft, and Ullman and Cormen,
>   Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein, concentrates on determining the growth
>   of the worst-case performance of the algorithm (an “upper bound”). A
>   prime goal in such analyses is to determine which algorithms are
>   optimal in the sense that a matching “lower bound” can be proved on
>   the worst-case performance of any algorithm for the same problem. We
>   use the term theory of algorithms to refer to this type of analysis.

Which explains the approach adopted in CLRS

It is also mentioned

> The second approach to the analysis of algorithms, popularized by
>   Knuth, concentrates on precise characterizations of the bestcase,
>   worst-case, and average-case performance of algorithms, using a
>   methodology that can be refined to produce increasingly precise
>   answers when desired. A prime goal in such analyses is to be able to
>   accurately predict the performance characteristics of particular
>   algorithms when run on particular computers, in order to be able to
>   predict resource usage, set parameters, and compare algorithms. This
>   approach is scientific: we build mathematical models to describe the
>   performance of real-world algorithm implementations, then use these
>   models to develop hypotheses that we validate through experimentation.

So this is the approach adopted by Knuth (I guess the analysis in "The art of computer programming" follow such approach).

I do get the general idea of course, but not the application, is there a specific application of these concepts you can point out? For example I do know the CLRS analysis of quicksort for example, how would this be any different from a scientific approach?

Comment: Sure.  Try reading each of those books.  They have many examples of that style of analysis.

Comment: You can also see Sedgewick's lectures on Coursera. Basically, the “theory of algorithms” approach (as in AHU / CLRS) is to analyze only the worst case, and to only care about the rate of growth, not the constant factor. Sedgewick has examples (using mergesort) of how the methods differ; just read further in the chapter or watch the videos/slides.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that's one of the things, worst case to me is related to $O(\cdot)$ notation. However CLRS defines and use also $\Omega(\cdot),\Theta(\cdot)$, which model some how best case as well, the $\Theta(\cdot)$ models both somehow. I really can't read the TAOCP for now, because the exposition the author provides about sorting algorithm is a bit unusual to me.

Comment: For TAOCP I'm not talking about the analysis, but the actual exposition of the pseuducode of the algorithm, mergesort for example is a bit unreadable to me.

Comment: You don't have to read TAOCP, the "scientific approach" is well covered in the introductory chapters of the Sedgewick  book using Java code. (BTW $O()$, $\Omega()$, $\Theta()$ as used in CLRS are about upper, lower and tight bounds all on the worst-case running time, they are not about worst-case, best-case, average-case.)

Comment: Sorry but I'm probably getting confused. If you have to search a specific element in an array wouldn't that take $\Omega(1)$? and that's the best case anyway, same for the sorting you can'd do any better than $\Omega(n \log n)$ if you use comparisons. Aren't these best cases?

Comment: No. If searching for an element in an array, the best case is that it happens to be right at the beginning, needing only one step (or a constant number). How frequently this happens depends on your input model, for your application. In many real-world cases this is depended on (e.g. LRU cache). Similarly with sorting an array that happens to be already (mostly) sorted or reverse-sorted (could be linear time), which happens frequently when users are clicking on columns in spreadsheets. (See also [the most-voted StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/).)